# How do I UPDATE (not add an additional) attachment in Atlassian Confluence with their Java API?

Tags: java, confluence

We have a custom plug-in that allows people to upload documents through the GUI, and add metadata about those documents within our plug-in. Also, another function of the plug-in, is we have an XML file being pushed to us via the Confluence SOAP service. This XML file is being attached to a specific file within the plug-in space, by the SOAP service, once a day.

We have now been charged with turning the process around. We will now make our own SOAP call to get the same XML file and attach it to the same page.

I can successfully attach a new file to the page, but when I try to update (replace) that XML file with a newer version, I end up uploading another file, so I am left with multiple copies of the file with the same name, which is not what we want.

Here is what I have that adds a new attachment, but does not update (replace) the attachment:

```
page = pageManager.getPage(spaceKey, pageTitle);

attachment = attachmentManager.getAttachment(page, attachmentFilename);
Attachment currentAttachment = null;

currentAttachment = (Attachment) attachment.clone();

attachment = new Attachment();
attachment.setFileName(attachmentFilename);
attachment.setContent(page);

attachment.setFileSize(fileSize);
attachment.setContentType(newAttachmentContentType);
attachment.setCreator(page.getCreator());
attachment.setCreationDate(date);
attachment.setComment(attachmentComment);

attachmentManager.saveAttachment(attachment, currentAttachment, dplAsStream);
```

Again, what I want is to replace filename.xml with an updated filename.xml, but what I am getting is filename.xml, filename.xml, filename.xml, etc.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no simple `updateAttachment` since the file storage follows a version-based approach. Every upload of the same file (by its filename) will be a newer version of the already present file without removing the older one.

To implement your update functionality it might be necessary to do multiple steps:

1. Check if the file to be uploaded already exists (=update)
2. [Remove a given version](https://docs.atlassian.com/confluence/latest/com/atlassian/confluence/pages/AttachmentManager.html#removeAttachmentFromServer(com.atlassian.confluence.pages.Attachment)) or [all previous versions](https://docs.atlassian.com/confluence/latest/com/atlassian/confluence/pages/AttachmentManager.html#removeAttachments(java.util.List)) using the AttachmentManager
3. Upload the file

Maybe the [CLI implementation](https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CSOAP/Documentation#Documentation-runFromAttachmentList) gives some more details how they made it because here you can run an update command.

Comment: I'll check out the link you provided ... thank you. I'm also concerned about keeping the versioning history that Confluence offers. If I were to go in through the GUI and upload the file manually, all previous versions will be shown. I need to keep that functionality as well.